# Styling clean div tags

Tags: html, css

In stylesheets you often see `div#id { /* something */ }` and `div.class { /* ... */ }` but how often do you see just `div { /* something */ }`?

Is it a bad idea to style div tags that have no #id or .class associated with them?

Comment: I don't think so, as long as the style info you put in them is shared by all DIV's. I didn't put this as an aswer as I'm not 100% certain, but it's worth considering... EDIT: I was spot on...

Comment: I personally like the approach where you use a container, and then style everything inside it by tag name. For example, [div id="menu"] has [ul]'s and [p]'s, and your CSS refers to everything by #menu ul, #menu p, etc. I find this to be much cleaner and intuitive (for me at least) than littering every single element with classes and/or ID's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessarily bad practice, as long as you're sure you want to apply this styling to every single `div` in your document. You can always override and / or add further down the cascading style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your purpose.

Styling all divs to be one specific style can be overridden.

So you may want to force height on all divs, but on divs with class hidden you want display none. Finally you may want a div with id = hello to have a red background.

Next you decide that you want a div with id=foo and class = bar to be have height:200.

```
div {
  height:100px;
}

div.hidden {
  display:none;
}

div#hello {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
div#id.bar {
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...it depends on what you want. If you want every single div tag in your markup to have the same style then it makes sense to do a tag selector instead of a class or id selector.

Answer (score 0):

As you normally use divs for a bunch of different stuff, I would answer "yes".